# Why instability and not unstability?

Tags: prefixes

Why do we go from using the prefix un- in unstable to using the prefix in- in instability?  Why can't we just keep using un-?

Comment: You might find the accepted answer on [this related ELU question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/15723/why-unequal-but-inequality) to be helpful.

Comment: very helpful. Academic words mostly came from Latin, which use in- as prefix, whereas commonly used words have a prefix of un-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to http://www.worldwidewords.org/qa/qa-unv1.htm words with a Germanic root use the un- prefix and words with a Romantic root use the in- suffix.

There are also the prefixes a- as in asexual and non- as in nondescript.

Unless you're a professor of linguistics and etymology I think your best bet is to use un-, which is the most common prefix, and learn which words use a different prefix on a case by case basis.

EDIT: I know this doesn't completely answer your question for why unstable turns into instability, but the truth is that although there is a *general* rule for which prefix to use, there are so many exceptions that it's pretty much arbitrary (without reason).